# can virus cause harddisk bad track?

Tags: hard-drive, virus

Last week I found my windows laptop bad track.I bought it less than a year.I dismantled it once to increase a DDR3 Memory about 9 months ago.I always download files from web.Recently I found many answers about virus cause harddisk bad track.I tried to repair my laptop but found many unrepairable bad track,the number was really amazing.I want to know whether the virus cause the unrepairable problems or others.

Comment: No;  Software cannot cause a HDD to have a bad track.  You need to replace your HDD since your current one has more then likely already failed.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible, it is highly unlikely.  Hard drives fail by the thousands on a daily basis.  Some manufacturers (Western digital being one of the worst IMHO) have a bad track record of producing faulty hard drives that fail after very minimum use.   Think about this issue from the view of the person who wrote the virus that you are infected with, if they make your machine create bad blocks (which would be difficult to do) on the hard drive, the computer will not be able to boot eventually and then the virus would not be running on your machine.  What would be the point of writing a malicious program if it does not have the ability to continue working?

Comment: Not just possible, its been [done](https://www.google.com/search?q=firmware+virus&oq=firmware+virus&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3439j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: How likely is it that this person has malware written by the NSA?  What you linked to was not written by your run of the mill group of wayward kids that hang out in IRC chat rooms.  I would imagine due to the resources of the NSA, that malware would be used in a very focused attack to retrieve data from specific computers.

Comment: all i am saying is firmware viruses are real.  read the kaspersky article, should be first.